# Trying to do a LEFT JOIN on two tables but want only one from the RIGHT TABLE

Tags: sql, join, left-join

So I have two tables.

`Table 1`

```
ID    Receiver  Some  Columns

1  43523  Ba  Baa

2  82822  Boo  Boo
```

`Table 2`

```
ID    Receiver  Some2  Columns2

1 - 43523  OO  JJ

2 - 43523  OO  NULL

3 - 43523  OO  YABA DABA
```

So, Now I want to do a `left join` where in I join only one of the matching rows from table 2. THe join will be on Receiver column, and the ID column in each table is different.

I tried left join, and it gave me everything from TABLE 2 (Understandably). I looked at other queries online but got lost.

Can anyone help me with this?

**EDIT**

Starting query (from OP's comments):

```
SELECT Table1.[ID],
       Table1.[Receiver],
       Table2.[Some2],
       Table1.[Some],
       Table1.[Columns]
  FROM Table1
  LEFT JOIN Table2
    ON Table1.Receiver = Table2.ReceiverID
 WHERE Some = 544
   AND Columns = 'xyz'
```

Comment: im not clear on what you are asking.  can you add a example of what you want the resultset to look like?

Comment: Specify your RDBMS. Also, you need to define which row you want to join on if more than one row is a join candidate (which of the 3 rows in `table2 2` do you want to join on and why?).  You just want to randomly join on one row?  And what if there are no matching rows in `table 2`, do you want a row returned, or no rows?

Comment: So you want all records of table 1 and with each only one record from table2? If so, which one? Or do you want aggregations from table 2, such as a string 'JJ, YABA DABA'?

Comment: @sstan, I am fine with joining any row in table 2, since the column I am concerned about is same for all the rows with same Receiver. Also, there will ALWAYS be a row with that receiver

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, I want all of Table 1, and only one row of table 2 that is matched using receiver and any record, since all will have the column that I want.

Comment: Each receiver is present in table2? And you are only interested in one column from the table? What is your DBMS? Postgres, SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL...?

Comment: Yes, each receiver is present in table 2, and yes I am interested in only one row of the table with matching receiver (because all I care about is the related column that is same for all rows). In above example, choosing either of the three occurrences will be fine, since I just care about table2.receiver, and table2.some2. 
It is sql server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your `left join` to a normal `join`, since you are always expecting a match.

And to limit the matches to a single row, you can use `row_number over ()`, where the `order by` clause is meaningless, since you don't care which row you are matching to.

```
SELECT Table1.[ID],
       Table1.[Receiver],
       t2.[Some2],
       Table1.[Some],
       Table1.[Columns]
  FROM Table1
  JOIN (SELECT *,
               row_number() over (partition by ReceiverID order by ReceiverID) as rn
          FROM Table2) t2
    ON Table1.Receiver = t2.ReceiverID
   AND t2.rn = 1
 WHERE Some = 544
   AND Columns = 'xyz'
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! Worked like a charm!

Comment: This is rather complex for the simple task at hand, but is the perfect solution as soon as more then one column from table 2 shall be retrieved. Built for the future, so to say :-)

Comment: As a matter of fact, I had to grab another column as well due to some changes in the scenario. Thanks for your help both of you @ThorstenKettner

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `group by` to make the `Receiver` column unique:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM Table1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 AS t2 ON t1.Receiver = t2.Receiver
GROUP BY t2.Receiver
```

Comment: Did not work. Column 'Table1.id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 0):

As you are only interested in one column which is the same for every record, you can use a subquery:

```
select t1.*, (select max(some2) from table2 t2 where t2.receiver = t1.receiver)
from table1 t1
```

(That column being always the same indicates a bad table design however.)

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from
    T1 as t1 inner join
    (select Receiver, min(Some2) as Some2 from T2 group by Receiver) as t2
        on t2.Receiver = t1.Receiver
```